# Moving my Ubuntu partition to the right so the unallocated space can merge

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

[Screenshot of my partitions shown on GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFiup.png)

These are my partitions:
EFI, unallocated space, my Ubuntu partition (sda9, filesystem is btrfs), unallocated space, and swap partition.

I need to somehow move sda9 to the right so the *unallocated space can merge*, and when I'll be installing Windows, I'll be able to create one partition for it **(just uninstalled windows and i need to reinstall it, some data from windows is on my ubuntu so i cannot remove it and install windows on freshly formatted drive)**.

What software or livecd system can I use to move my partition so the unallocated space can merge? Note that I currently have only one USB pendrive (128gb), tho I can use Rufus or Etcher to flash some livecd from my VM (directly connecting USB to my VM on Ubuntu, so it mounts on the VM and unmounts on Ubuntu, so I can modify it through the VM (tested, it works)). I am not any linux expert, so I don't know how to do it or I'm scared to try my own ideas (which I don't even have), so any help will be appreciated. I tried searching the internet for the same problem, but couldn't find anyone which has the exact same. Sorry if I missed some answer.

**Edit: I want my Ubuntu partition to stay intact, because when the unallocated space will merge, I'll create one big NTFS partition for Windows from it.**

Comment: You are probably better off wiping the drive and reinstalling both operating systems. You can't move partitions

Comment: Do you know any cloud service where I can store around 60 gb of data for free privately?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  Can you use the flash drive and possibly get another flash drive for your installation media?  They are inexpensive.  Where do you normally keep your backups?

Comment: Usually I don't have to keep backups, or I store some of them on my pendrive. Right now, all of my backups from my pendrive along with some other personal files from Windows are on my Ubuntu partition.

Comment: I have also read that it may be possible to move the free space by using GParted live.

Comment: @BillyFakeyMakey moving partitions around is dangerous, and you can't really 'change' positions of partitions without requiring a lot of disk data and time.  It's easier to nuke and reinstall typically than to move around 100s of GBs of data just to move partitions around.

Comment: Backups are critical before any major system change. You should have both Windows & Ubuntu backups & live installer for Ubuntu & Windows repair/recovery flash drive. Live installer can be a smaller flash drive. Not sure of Windows requirements, now but used to be at least 8GB which still is a lower cost flash drive. Only get USB3 drives: I use these, but any decent flash drive will work. https://www.microcenter.com/category/4294966790/usb-flash-drives You also have btrfs file system which may have unique requirements.

Comment: I have managed to keep a backup of my important files on the same usb drive as gparted live usb, moved my partition, then i installed ventoy, added windows, ubuntu, and gparted on it. I also added a backup of my important files on it too by adding to my personal folder ".ventoyignore". Rn installing windows and everything seems to work :)